# Extract every expression between parentheses in python

Tags: python, regex, string, extract

I'm trying to write a gdb like debugger and I'm experiencing a problem extracting expressions between parentheses (from a string).

For example, I want the output of the following code:

```py
extract_expression('*((*0x802F18B4) + 4)')
```

to be:

```py
['(*0x802F18B4)', '((*0x802F18B4) + 4)', '*((*0x802F18B4) + 4)']
```

The most inner element in the parentheses to the outer one.

Comment: Can you show an example with a valid python expression? Or is the expression `*((*0x802F18B4) + 4)` a string?

Comment: Yep it is a string

Comment: This expression is a string i then evaluate with python

Comment: Your expected result is inconsistent wrt the nesting level of parentheses. It should be `['*0x802F18B4', '(*0x802F18B4) + 4', '*((*0x802F18B4) + 4)']` or `['(*0x802F18B4)', '((*0x802F18B4) + 4)', "('*((*0x802F18B4) + 4)')"]`.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is only tested with the input and output you provided.

Maybe it can be solved with regex in a simpler and more performant way.

```py
def extract_expression(expression):
    open_parenthese_indexes = [i for i, c in enumerate(expression) if c == '(']
    close_parenthese_indexes = [i for i, c in enumerate(expression) if c == ')']

    close_parenthese_indexes.reverse()

    res = [expression]
    for i, index in enumerate(open_parenthese_indexes):
        start_index = index
        end_index = close_parenthese_indexes[i] + 1
        res.append(expression[start_index:end_index])
    res.reverse()

    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    expected_result = ['(*0x802F18B4)', '((*0x802F18B4) + 4)', '*((*0x802F18B4) + 4)']
    result = extract_expression('*((*0x802F18B4) + 4)')
    assert expected_result == result
```